# Jquery data() storage

Tags: jquery, data-storage

Can any one tell me where jquery `data()` stores the data and when it is get erased and how?

Is there any performance issue if I use this to store ajax call result?

For example:

```
$("body").data("test", { myData: 'abcd'});
```

Comment: it is stored at the client side only , i was using jquery data and jquery meta data plugins to retrive the data and never ran into any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the content from jquery

The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore free from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves the page. We can set several distinct values for a single element and retrieve them later:

Comment: thanks @gov. But in the following article http://apheliondynamics.com/blog/2010/01/19/the-power-of-jquery-data-and-a-practical-example/article it is mentioned that data() stores the content in cache. So I was confused when actually the cache is cleared !

Comment: @ANP go to this page , http://www.art.com/gallery/id--c23944/fine-art-prints.htm?ui=351BF178E486494982CDA4842EB6BD55 and do a view source and check for hiddenvalues , then clear caches from your browser, still you can see the values/// they are stored as a part of dom structure it selef, i don't think they are stored in cache...

Answer (score 29):

All data is stored inside a property of the `jQuery` object named `cache`. Log the contents of `$.cache` in your console to see all data and events associated with any DOM element.

The way jQuery links up a DOM object with an object in this cache is by manipulating the DOM object. Say we have a input element

```
<input type="text" value="hello" />
```

which has a data key named "foo"

```
$(e).data("foo", "bar");
```

Now jQuery maintains a random string of the form `jQuery<current time in ms>`, for example, `jQuery1291790929680`, which is also accessible by `$.expando`. jQuery adds this expando string as a key to each DOM object that has an associated data item or event. So the DOM object for the above input element will contain this expando key with some integer value such as:

```
jQuery1291790929680: 4
```

4 is just a random example, but this number denotes an index in the `$.cache` object, where the associated data and events for this DOM object are stored. So given this information, to retrieve the data of the above input element, we can indirectly write:

```
$.cache[4]["foo"]
```

which should return "bar", which is an indirect way of writing `$(e).data("foo")`.

An [illustrated example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/8qRrY/) of the above nonsense :)

Comment: I am really grateful for your explanation.